# Docusign reminders for PowerForms users

Tags: docusignapi

How I can setup reminders for PowerForm users?

For example a user opened my PowerForm link but did not finished the signing. An envelope is created for that user and showing up in "Waiting for Others" and I can manually re-send the envelope. But I would like to know if the "Reminders and Expiration" notifications can work for PowerForm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that if you set the original template that was used to create the PowerForm to send reminders when you want to.
That is in the web app on the "Advanced Options" (click "edit") on the right.
They may be disabled (not allow you to make changes) if the admin of the account does not allow senders to customize this. You would have to go to the Settings up and choose "Reminders and Expiration" from the menu and then check "Allow senders to override account defaults". That would also enable you to change the account's defaults for all envelopes.

Comment: Thanks Inbar. I also thought the same and setup the reminders on template but it didn't worked.  I have sandbox account and I have reminders enabled in admin section but it doesn't work for PowerForms.

Comment: "If the envelope gets set to "Waiting for Others" or "Needs to Sign" instead of added to the Draft folder then it is a live envelope and all Reminders and Expirations for that envelope should be active. With Reminders only the active Recipient (the person responsible to take action) gets a notification to continue the envelope process."

Comment: https://support.docusign.com/s/question/0D51W00007lf9pP/do-the-reminders-and-expiration-settings-work-for-incomplete-powerforms